# iOS Distribution(UDID/Adhoc) pem file not sending notifcation

Tags: ios, push-notification

I have generate the push notifications certificates in Our Apple Id and also generate the `.pem` and `.p12` files.

We get the notifications from development `.pem` file but it's not working in
 distribution `.pem` file. I tried to Revoke the Old Certificates and
 generate a new one.

While Using an Online Push Notification Check - I got this issue:

> Got an Issue (****.pem | 4269 | application/x-x509-ca-cert)

It's from http://pushtry.com/, but
 work on another Online Push Notifications Website(http://apns-gcm.bryantan.info/).

Development `.pem` is Working, But why not a Distribution(AdHoc and App Store).

I face this issues from last one week but still I don't get the notifications in Application. Previous the `.pem` file is working but it stopped working now.

Laravel is used as Backend to Push notificaiton :
Every thing is right over there.

All the certificates and provisional profiles are valid.
No sweat in creating `.p12` and `.pem` files.

Yet can't send notification

Hope some on can help.

Answer (score 0):

It's backend side they have to update code for live 
They coded for sandbox 
 "ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195" 
Replace above line in backend or php side with below line
 "ssl://gateway.apple.push.apple.com:2195"

Also, You can test push notification for both mode using below project.
https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher

Comment: If you're still get any issue then please mention here for more help and support

Comment: Bro thanks for the reply. But all the code on backEnd are up to date, Its already set to production, its not in sandbox

Comment: Ok, So you can check your using https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher. Your push certificates is working or not.

Comment: dude I think the certificate is fine ! distribution profile sends notification using NWPusher ! What could the be the possible source for the problem ?? Is there is any way that pem file generated using command be corrupted ?? But there is no error while using those pem on server Side !

Comment: I’ve faced this issue many times for push notifications. It’s from backend side only. Because, our certificates is correct and working. May be they forgot to link new (distribution) .pem file path in code (php side)

Comment: I my self ensured that they attach the correct file. And I have gone through the code, they were ok ! is there is any posibility that I might have generated improper pem ?